# Using the tangent to the curve to find when it matches another equation

Tags: calculus

Find the point at which the tangent to the curve $y=x^2$ has the equation $2x+y+1=0$?

So I find the tangent to the curve of the equation but then to find the point what do I do next like sub it in?

Comment: What have you done so far? Include that in the question

Comment: What happens if you calculate the intersection(s) between that parabola and that line?

Answer (score 0):

A line is tangent to a curve if:

(1) the line intersects the curve, and

(2) at an intersection point, the slope of the curve at that point equals the slope of the line.

If you are sure that the given line is tangent to the given point, you may be able to use just one of those facts to find the point. In fact, that will work in your particular problem. If you are not sure, or as a check, you could check both facts. You could use a graphing calculator, program, or [web page](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) for a final check.

Try these hints. If you still cannot answer the question, add what you have tried to your question and ask for more help (in your question).